# Crear 2 referencias a un mismo modelo en otro Rails: 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo 2 modelos uno de usuarios y otro de artículos

Users:
     id
     name
     email
     password
     rol

Articles:
     id
     titulo
     body

Quiero que mi articulo tenga 2 referencias a mi tabla usuarios uno para el usuario que creo el articulo y otro para el usuario (rol: administrador) que lo aprobó, pero no se como hacerlo sin hacer una relación muchos a muchos que me parece mucho para este caso que solo necesito que un registro este relacionado con 2 usuarios

al final Artículos debe quedar así

Articles:

id
 titulo
 body
 user_id <== (rol admin/moderador) — Ambos del
    modelo User
 user_id  <==(rol usuario)

Ya tengo establecido los roles con CAN CAN solo no se como hacer este tipo de relación.

Los artículos no tienen mas relaciones con ningún otro usuario que el que lo creo y el que lo aprobó.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer la relación de `Articles` tal como la muestras, solo que debes utilizar nombres de llaves distintos; por ejemplo:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User"
end
```

Aquí `class_name: "User"` es la que hace que `admin` apunte a la tabla `users`, pero toma la llave `admin_id` en lugar de `user_id` debido a los valores por defecto de *Rails* (i.e. toma el nombre de la relación y le agrega `_id`).

En la migración `CreateArticles` deberás incluir las dos columnas:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      # ...
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :admin_id
    end
  end
end
```

Con esta relación podrás obtener el usuario o administrador de un artículo específico utilizando `user` o `admin` respectivamente; por ejemplo, para el artículo con `id == 1`:

```
Article.find(1).user
Article.find(1).admin
```